# How to join these two models into a viewmodel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my first ASP project and I am really struggling with how to join multiple tables together into a viewmodel. I have a model called project that will be used to create new projects and have them inserted into the database.

```
using System;

namespace vasttPM1.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Enddate { get; set; }
        public string Installer { get; set; }
        public int ProjectNumber { get; set; }
        public string ProjectManager { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        public string ProjectType { get; set; }
        public string Building { get; set; }
        public string Rooms { get; set; }
        public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
        public int Status { set; get; }
    }
}
```

I have a static table in the DB called ProjectStatus that has some fields associated to each project. Mainly the fields Status and Percent.

So what I am trying to do is get the information in the model above and get the status, percent from the projectstatus table where `project.status = projectstatus.id`.

Then combine the results into a viewmodel.

It sounds easy but I am really struggling with how to make this work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using EF Core Code First?

Comment: Yes I created the model above, then generated the CRUD scaffolding that created the views, controller etc. Did the migration which created the table and everything seems to be working with creating new projects, viewing details etc. On the Index page though instead of displaying the project in table of format I want to display the project and get the status, and percent fields from the static "projectstatus" table.

Comment: Do you want all of that data to show up in one row (project, status, percent fields)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to take two tables and put them into one view model. To do this you'll need to create a new view model class with the properties you want. For example:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Status { set; get; }
    public int Percent { set; get; }
}
```

You can then join the two tables together using a Linq query and select them into the new object like this:

```
var results = (from p in db.Project
              join ps in db.ProjectStatus on p.Status equals ps.Id
              select new ProjectViewModel()
              {
                  ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
                  Status = ps.StatusName,
                  Percent = ps.PercentComplete
              }).ToList();
```

That should create for you a list of ProjectViewModels that you can then use in your view. I may have some of your property or column names incorrect. I had to guess on what they might be in your ProjectStatus table.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. A couple of questions. In the above code would that go in the controller or in the viewmodel object? I am getting an error on the db. stating the name 'db' does not exist in the current context. Any ideas how to resolve that?

Comment: db is a reference to your DataContext object. It may be named something different in your project. The `var results` piece of code would go in your controller in the Get method. You can store you ViewModel wherever you'd prefer. Some people create a separate project, or you can put it in the Models folder. Then wherever your current Project model is referenced, you would need to change it to ProjectViewModel. That would occur in the controller and in the view.

Comment: One important note, you won't be able to use the out of the box scaffolding code for updates because you can't put a ViewModel back into the database. You would need to get the Project and ProjectStatus objects and update them with the data from the ProjectViewModel, assuming this page allows updates.

Comment: Thank you. I only plan to use the viewmodel to display an overall view of the projects. I will be using a different view/controller to create new projects/edit them etc.

Comment: Great! Then this should work for you. If so, please be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm playing with this now. Should I be doing return(results) or return something else?

Comment: Do you mean in the controller? If so, you would normally do `return View(viewModelInstance)`, where viewModelInstance is what you created and what to bind in your view.