# How to move two tables into one view model in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, join, viewmodel

I want to move or get two tables into one view model but I don't know how do it.

This is my view model:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class PagesArchiveViewModel
    {
        public List<PagesTable> PagesTableList { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my join command for two table:

```
var twotable = (from user in _db.UserTable
                join Page in _db.PagesTable
                     on user.Id equals Page.UserID
                where user.Active_From_Admin == true &&
                      
user.Active_From_User == true && 
                      user.PhoneNumberConfirmed == true &&
                      Page.Active_From_User == true && 
                      Page.PageActivityID == 1
                select new
                       {
                             PScore = user.News_Score_Count + user.Buy_Score_Count,
                             PagesID = Page.PagesID,
                             Author = Page.Author,
                             PageTypeID = Page.PageTypeID,
                             PageTitle = Page.PageTitle,
                             PageDescription = Page.PageDescription,
                             PageAdress = Page.PageAdress,
                             PageMetaTag = Page.PageMetaTag,
                             PageImage = Page.PageImage,
                             PageActivityID = Page.PageActivityID,
                             LikeModeID = Page.LikeModeID,
                             Like = Page.Like,
                             DisLike = Page.DisLike,
                             Active_From_User = Page.Active_From_User,
                         }).OrderByDescending(a => a.PScore).ToList();
```

I want send two tables var in this code:

```
PagesArchiveViewModel = new PagesArchiveViewModel()
            {
               
            };
```

Comment: Do you want "PagesArchiveViewModel = new PagesArchiveViewModel()
            {
               PagesTableList=...;     PagingInfo =...;
            };"    ? Have a look at[join these two models into a viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010205/how-to-join-these-two-models-into-a-viewmodel).

Comment: no it dont help me i want send the list which combined with two tables into view

Comment: "send the list which combined with two tables into view" Do you mean "return View(twotable);" ? Could you share your attempt? What's the error you meet?